# grep all lines for a specific date in log-files

Tags: bash, date, grep

I need to grep all lines for "yesterday" in /var/log/messages.
When I use following snippet, I get zero results due to the fact that the dates are in the format "Jun  9". (It doesn't show here, but in the log file, the days of the month are padded with an extra space when smaller than 10).

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep `date --date="yesterday" +%b\ %e`
```

When I enter

```
$ date --date="yesterday" +%b\ %e
```

on the commandline, it returns yesterday's date, with padding.

But when I combine it with grep and the backticks, the extra padding gets suppressed, which gives me zero results.

What do I need to change so that the "date" gets evaluated *with* extra padding?

Comment: Use `$()` for command substitution instead of backticks for improved readability and [other benefits](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by putting quotes around the backticks:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep "`date --date="yesterday" +%b\ %e`"
```

Comment: Caveat: Date can output localized month name while syslog dates are always in English.